# How can I add different navbar logos for each 'section' in a single page website during scrolling in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set different versions of logos to different sections during scrolling. I have tried using javascript to set the logos using scroll function to different height but it doesn't work for different devices. I've tried like this but this doesn't work for different screen sizes. Do I need to take different approach? How can I do this?

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>600) {
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO-WHITE.png");
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO.png");
        }
    })
})

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>1200) {
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO-BLACK.png");
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO.png");
        }
    })
})

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>1800) {
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO-WHITE.png");
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO.png");
        }
    })
})

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>2400) {
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO-BLACK.png");
        }
        else{
            $(".navbar .navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/icons/LOGO.png");
        }
    })
})
```